# How to use Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am new to selenium. I need to arrive the following in my code.

I do have:

1. Login.Java --> Does the login the website.
2. settings.java --> Does the Change some info in settings.
3. Logout --> Logout the website.

Each single code runs fine... Now i need to arrive in the following way.

Creating Sanity.Java -->

calling Login.java
calling settings.java
calling logout.java

After runng login.java, when calling settings.java it opens another browser.. Instead on running the same window, how to do this.

My Plan is: I will break down the each functionality and i will call these each functionality scrip in the main.java file..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also think of clubbing your Selenium WebDriver test with the help of Test Framework **[TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/selenium.html)**, in this you will write a TestSuite XML say sanity.xml and write 3 test nodes that calls your class files including the method name. Now let's say you create a BaseTest class that is extended by every Test class like login.java, settings.java & logout.java. 
In TestNG you have annotations like @BeforeSuite, @Test, @AfterSuite

So you will write methods in BaseTest class with @BeforeSuite that does the object creation of your WebDriver, make this driver static in your base class which will be created only once in your @BeforeSuite method and later be used directly in your future test.

@Test annotation will be used in login.java's method to make it consider as Test method

In @AfterSuite you will write code for closing your WebDriver instance. 
Your structure of BaseTest will look somewhat like below

```
public class BaseTest{
    public static WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeSuite(alwaysRun = true)
    public void startSuite(){
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }

    @AfterSuite(alwaysRun = true)
    public void endSuite(){
        driver.quit();
    }

}

public class Login extends BaseTest{
    @Test
    public void doLogin(){
        WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='username']"));
        username.sendKeys("USERNAME");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 1):

Think about using page objects.

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects

Notice that you are passing the web driver around.

Answer (score 0):

Your plan looks good.
The reason that a new browser opens on every class is that you are creating a new instance of the WebDriver in them.
Something like: `WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver()`
You should create the WebDriver **once** in your test or main method and pass it as an argument to the action methods.
Don't forget to close it after you've finished your flow.

Good luck,
Ittiel

Answer (score 0):

I arrived this method.. Any suggestion that it looks ok?

```
1. DriverManager.Java

a. Created static driver instance and the method getDriver.

2. Login.java

a. Imported the Drivermanager package.
b. WebDriver driver=DriverManager.getWebDriver();
c. test Continiues
```

Same for Settings and Logout..

Now i called these all in Sanity..

Comment: Looks good, so with the help of FactoryMethod design pattern you will maintain single copy of your driver which will be used across all your sanity test. You can also keep a local reference in your sanity class which is instantiated from the DriverManager class in the beginning and other methods just uses the same local reference, here we won't be creating new instance but just re-using single instance.